# Inspecting nil value returned by NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c

We can create a class by using `NSClassFromString`:

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"someClass");
id object = [[class alloc] init];
[object test];
```

It's no problem here.

`NSClassFromString` would return `nil` if a class given by the string does not exist.

Fair enough and calling `[object test];`, when object is nil (because class is `nil`) would not cause any problem.

***As an experiment***, I changed `@"someClass"` to something else that does not exist.
By logging the value of `class` (when `NSClassFromString` returns `nil`) it shows `0x0`.
And subsequently I tried to replace as a test:

`id object = [[class alloc] init];`

with the following one by one:

```
id object = [[Nil alloc] init];

id object = [[nil alloc] init];

id object = [[NSNull alloc] init];
```

Only `id object = [[NSNull alloc] init];` does not cause any compile error but will cause a crash when it reaches to this line:

```
[object test];
```

***So my question is***, why can't I replace `class` with either `nil` or `Nil`, but when `NSClassFromString` returns `nil` and assign it to `Class class` and calling this `[[class alloc] init];` would work? `class` is also `nil` here.

Adding error message for cases when `id object = [[Nil alloc] init];` or `id object = [[nil alloc] init];` is applied.

> Bad receiver type of 'void *'.

Comment: Also not part of your question but worth noting that using NSNull and then trying to call that `test` method causes a crash because `NSNull` is an actual object type (derived from `NSObject`) and that is an unrecognized selector for that object.

Comment: What? NSNull is a class, and its singleton is not nil.  And what does it have to do with your question?

Comment: i will suggest to check this [reference link](http://nshipster.com/nil/)

Comment: You can send a message to a pointer to nil (`id thing = nil; thing = [[thing alloc] init];`) which will return nil, but not to nil itself. In the same way, you can't message an `int`: `int i = 3; [[i alloc] init];`

Comment: @pawan Thanks for link; I read that long time ago. I know the difference.

Comment: @nevanking Thanks for response. Can you elaborate a bit on _"which will return nil, but not to nil itself."_?

Comment: @Unheilig I'm not great at this, so take what I say with a grain of salt, but I was saying that there's a difference between nil and a pointer to nil. Something like `id obj = nil` is making a pointer to nil, which can be messaged. In Objective-C, the receiver of a message is always a pointer (pointer to an `NSString`, pointer to a `UIView` etc). So presumably the compiler is telling you that nil is an invalid receiver for a message.

Comment: @nevanking: `nil` is a valid receiver for a message.

Comment: @Unheilig: Are you positive this results in a compiler error? I tested it (with this code: https://gist.github.com/mdippery/9792183) and it compiled fine (albeit with a warning), and ran fine, too.

Comment: @mipadi Thanks for the follow-up and the gist; yes, what I got is exactly the same (i.e. `id myObject = [[nil alloc] init];`) and the error that prevents compilation is `Bad receiver type of 'void *'` as mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

`nil` is of type `void*`, not `id`.  You cannot send messages to a `void*`.

NULL, Nil, and nil are type `void*` so that may be assigned to anything.  If nil was type `id` then you couldn't do this:

```
char* foo = nil;
```

which is not a useful limitation.

If you really want to send a message to `nil` you need to cast it to the correct type:

```
[(id)nil description];
```

Comment: nil is (id)0  means literal null value for Objective-C objects. and NULL  is (void *)0 literal null value for C pointers

Comment: Thanks for response. So, can we safely say (quoting from mircotherion's answer below) that we the runtime sees `nil` it would wrap a `struct` for us, but when I manually make it `nil` then it is not OK? Other words, I would like to understand why when I do `[[nil alloc] init];` is not OK, but when `NSClassFromString` returns a `nil` value to `class`, calling `[[class alloc] init];` is OK. But if I could confirm that the runtime does in fact wrap a `struct` around `nil` to make it `id` and that's why it works, I'd settle my curiosity with that.

Comment: @Unheilig: The compiler should just generate warnings for `[nil alloc] init]`, not errors, and the compiled project will run, but `[nil alloc] init]` returns a `nil` object. The runtime doesn't "wrap" nil in a struct or anything else -- the Objective-C runtime just has special handling for sending messages to `nil`.

Comment: @mipadi Thanks. It is an error that prevents compilation.

Comment: @pawan `nil` is `void*` in Obj-C, and `nullptr_t` in Obj-C++. You cannot send messages to either of those types, and the compiler will generate an error.

Comment: @Unheilig It has nothing to do with the runtime.  The compiler stops you from sending a message to void* in the same way it stops you from assigning an int to a char*.  It's simple static type checking.  At runtime, on the other hand, a zero is zero and sending a message to zero is OK.

Comment: @Darren Nice analysis. "static type checking" at compile-time is understandable to me. But how and what makes it possible that  "a zero is zero and sending a zero a message" at runtime is OK, would you happen to know the subtleties? Other words, what does it do to make it possible at runtime under the hood?

Comment: `nil` and `(id)0` and `(NSInteger)0` all have the same representation at runtime (a pointer-sized zero). You could use any of the three as the receiver of a message with identical results, if the compiler's type checker didn't stop you first.

Comment: @GregParker I am about to get the "aha" moment, but - so that means that if there were a compiler flag that I could use to bypass the compiler error and run it with `[[nil alloc] init];`, it would work  (given what you have said)? It doesn't now, because the error prevents compilation (stops me) in the first place?

Comment: @Unheilig Yes, that's correct.  When you use a typecast like `[(id)nil foo];` you override the compiler's default type checking and force it to compile.

Comment: @Darren `void *` in C is useful because it allows us to typecast a pointer to any type (hope my reasoning is not wrong, if so, correct me). Based on your example, can we safely say that we could as well do for ex: `(NSString *) nil = @"karma chameleon";`? I am asking because it seems like my question somehow skim through the subject as to why Obj-C being so dynamic. Given what @GregParker mentions above, it seems that during runtime `nil` is of the representations he mentioned, but during compile-time not so. The intricacies regarding to this between compile and runtime fascinates me. Thanks.

Comment: I faced the same problem but in Swift, and my app crash in this line: 
 let customBlurClass: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect")!
my full used code is: 
let customBlurClass: AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect")!
        let customBlurObject: NSObject.Type = customBlurClass as! NSObject.Type
        self.blurEffect = customBlurObject.init() as! UIBlurEffect
        self.blurEffect.setValue(1.0, forKeyPath: "scale")
        self.blurEffect.setValue(radius, forKeyPath: "blurRadius")
        super.init(effect: radius == 0 ? nil : self.blurEffect)

Comment: any hepl please in Swfit

Answer (score 3):

The Objective C runtime can handle the runtime situation of sending a message to `nil`, but if you already know at compile time that the target is `nil`, nothing good can possibly come out of it, so the compiler is doing you a favor by flagging a construct that is known not to accomplish anything.

**Edit:** @Darren is right, `nil` is a `void *`, not an `id`, so this fails for type checking reasons. Something like `[[(id)nil alloc] init]` does in fact compile. I still think a compiler *should* flag sending messages to known `nil`s, but as a matter of fact, it *doesn't*.